# Rotating Loaders in CSS

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

First of all, sorry if the title is wrong because I don't know if these are actually called rotating loaders or not. This is what I am talking about: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKmYx/)

I have 2 problems with these loaders,

- in .chrome-loader, if I set `height: 50px; width: 50px;`, and and in `.ring-maker` set `top: 2.5px; left: 2.5px` it doesn't work very well. Does px unit support values upto 2 decimal places? I guess they don't. So what can I do to fix it? I basically want to make it of same size as the ones above.  Perhaps, some other unit?
- For `.win8-loader` I set this CSS animation for first dot.

  ```
  @-webkit-keyframe win8dot1 {
      0% {left: -10px;}
      33% {left: 500px;}
      66% {left: 780px;}
      100% {left: 1280px;}
  }
  ```

  But it doesn't work. The first dot doesn't even move.

PS: are names like `abc1-de2` allowed for keyframes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct 2 problems

Your CSS

```
.win8-loader .dot1 { -webkit-animation: win8-dot1 2.5s infinite linear; }

@-webkit-keyframe win8dot1 {
```

corrected:

```
.win8-loader .dot1 { -webkit-animation: win8dot1 2.5s infinite linear; }

@-webkit-keyframes win8dot1 {
```